# How to combine the two outcomes from sql into one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two working sql queries:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM customer  
WHERE customer.customer_id = ( 
    SELECT customer_id FROM rental  
    WHERE return_date IS NULL  
    ORDER BY rental_date ASC LIMIT 1 );
```

and

```
SELECT rental_date
FROM rental 
WHERE return_date IS NULL 
ORDER BY rental_date ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Both of them returns a one line outcome.
My question is how can I combine the two outcomes into one as the following:

```
first_name | last_name | rental_date 
aaa           bbb         2022-5-25
```

Comment: It is only for 1 record? Or it will be more then 1?

Comment: @DaminiSuthar It should be only 1

Comment: @XJ JING  Added answer. Let me know if its works.

Comment: @DaminiSuthar Actually, I reviewed the question and realized that it should return all names and rental_date with the smallest rental_date.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `customer_id` is the foreign key in rental table. So you can apply join

```
SELECT C.first_name, C.last_name , R.rental_date
FROM customer AS C 
INNER JOIN rental AS R ON  C.customer_id = R.customer_id 
WHERE R.return_date IS NULL
ORDER BY R.rental_date ASC LIMIT 1
```

Or for all the firstname, lastname

```
SELECT first_name,  last_name ,  
(SELECT  MIN(job_date) FROM rental)AS min_job_date, 
FROM customer  
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: When I was reviewing the question, I realized that it should not return only one row, instead, it should print all names with the smallest date. It would be great if you could throw some hint on how to solve this

Comment: okay I got it.. I have edited the second answer.

Comment: @XIJING Please check answer again.